# Por que a imagem fica distorcida(não mantém as proporções) na ImageView?

Tags: java, android, imageview

Tenho algumas imagens dentro da pasta `drawable` e chamo elas via código:

```
 public void inserindoImage(ImageView image,int rid,LinearLayout linear )
    {
        image.setBackgroundResource(rid);
        linear.addView(image);
    }
```

Ao chamar essa função a imagem vai na tela.

**e fica assim**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**imagem original**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber como fazer a imagem manter a proporção na `imagemView`, como podem ver há uma deformação na imagem.

**xml**

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearImage"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <!--Imagem vem aqui-->
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

No caso coloquei um só, mas vem mais imagem por isso o `scroolView`.

Comment: A seguir a `image.setBackgroundResource(rid);` coloque `image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);`

Comment: Está a definir algum LayoutParameters para a ImageView? Adicione todo o código relevante.

Comment: Reparei agora que me enganei no scaleType, não é CENTER mas sim CENTER_INSIDE: `image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);`

Comment: @ramaral de uma olhada no edição vê se fica mais claro, tentei mas não mudou nada, analisando a imagem ela se ajusta no comprimento da tela mas altura não, precisava mexer na altura.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Substitua `image.setBackgroundResource(rid);` por `image.setImageResource(rid);`

[setBackgroundResource()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29) atribui a imagem ao *background* da *view* fazendo com que ela "estique" de forma a preenchê-lo todo.

Por sua vez [setImageResource()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29) atribui a imagem ao conteúdo da ImageView, levando em conta as suas dimensões.

Por principio, sempre que cria uma *View*, deverá também indicar qual o LayoutParams a utilizar por ela.

Altere o método **inserindoImage()** para:

```
public void inserindoImage(ImageView image,int rid,LinearLayout linear )
{
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params =
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                      ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    image.setLayoutParams(params);
    image.setImageResource(rid);
    linear.addView(image);
}
```

Comment: deu certo, mas ficou com um espaço tanto para cima quanto para baixo da imagem, olha a edição que postei o resultado

Comment: Isso é outro problema, faça nova pergunta. Coloque o xml que produzem o resultado que postou. No xml não vejo de onde vem o *background* vermelho

Comment: vermelho vem `Relative Layout`

Comment: fiz outra pergunta segue o link http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119898/como-resolver-espa%C3%A7o-formado-numa-linear-layout-ao-criar-imagew-via-c%C3%B3digo