# Como eliminar espaço extra formado numa LinearLayout ao criar ImageView via código?

Tags: java, android, imageview

Estou a utilizar este código para criar uma *ImageView* e adicioná-la a um *LinearLayout*:

```
public void inserindoImage(ImageView image,int rid,LinearLayout linear )
{
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params =
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                      ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    image.setLayoutParams(params);
    image.setImageResource(rid);
    linear.addView(image);
}
```

Só que `LinearLayout` não acompanhou a `imageView` e ficou um espaço em cima e em baixo da imagem.

segue as imagem da tela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**código xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

    tools:context="com.teste.teste1.Principal"
    android:background="#FFEC0D0D">

<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/linearImage"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <!--Imagem vem aqui-->
              </LinearLayout>
               <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/linearImage2"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <!--Imagem vem aqui-->
              </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
           </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Como posso eliminar esse espaço?

Comment: É necessário ter esses *LinearLayout* todos? Não pode ser apenas um e colocar lá a imagens todas?

Comment: @ramaral sim pois a vezes eu jogo texto lá

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inicialmente pensei que era um problema de *layout* mas não.

A imagem está a ser redimensionada quando é atribuída à *ImageView*, no entanto os seus limites(*bounds*) mantêm as dimensões originais, fazendo com que o *Layout* que a contém ajuste as suas dimensões de acordo com elas.

É necessário indicar à *ImageView* que ajuste os seus limites ao tamanho da imagem redimensionada, através de [setAdjustViewBounds(true)](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setAdjustViewBounds%28boolean%29).

Altere o código para:

```
public void inserindoImage(ImageView image, int rid, LinearLayout linear )
{
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params =
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                          ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    //Caso queira definir uma margem entre imagens
    params.setMargins(0,10,0,0);
    image.setLayoutParams(params);

    image.setImageResource(rid);
    image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    linear.addView(image);
}
```